# Eclipse sets watchpoints instead of breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

This happened to me once before.  Right click the margin and Toggle Breakpoint or Ctrl Shift B or double click margin usually gives a breakpoint with a blue circle.  But today Eclipse only sets watchpoints with a glasses and pencil icon.  This happened to me once before, and I think it just went away.  Does anyone know how to fix this.  I want breakpoints not watchpoints.

Answer (score 1):

This happends when you toggle a field. 
(Eclipse will normally automatically set the appropriate type of breakpoint)

In some cases Eclipse seems to fail to register that you selected a method for example instead of a field. When this occurs, just set your cursor on the appropriate word (for example getX() ) until eclipse notices it. (when this is the case, you will see a blue bar at the left, selecting every line of that method)